# Why is there the software-rec tag?

Tags: discussion

If "SU doesn't do software recomendation questions", how come we have the https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec tag, with 1,517 questions with up to 95 upvotes?

Comment: So we can tag questions that we know are bad and will eventually be closed? idk, good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of reasons to pick from:

1. Not every question that deserves the tag deserves to be closed.
2. Having a common tag for questions that fit into this problematic category is helpful during cleanups.
3. Removing the tag does not remove the problem.
4. Secretly everybody loves a good [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) question.

Comment: You are so right! I even had a flag declined because the question was a perfect recommendation question and did not need to be closed. It's only low-quality, no-background-research questions that need to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree! I vote to remove the tag permanently, if we are to ban software recommendations!

I believe that the people who *would* read the tag would know that we don't do software recommendations usually anyways, so I don't see why we need it around

Comment: I think prior to removing the tag, we should use its existence to evaluate if these tagged questions can be improved, merged, closed, etc